# docker—run nginx not allways working

Tags: nginx, docker

for learning purposes I have created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10

RUN useradd -m --password=node node && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y curl && \
  apt-get install -y openssl && \
  apt-get install -y nginx && \
  apt-get -qy autoremove

COPY . /home/node/xxx.com

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && \
  cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled && \
  ln -s /home/node/xxx.com/xxx.nginx.conf default

WORKDIR /home/node

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs 

RUN curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable && \
  /bin/bash -l -c "rvm requirements" && \
  /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.0" && \
  /bin/bash -l -c "gem update --system" && \
  /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc" && \
  /bin/bash -l -c "gem install compass  --no-ri --no-rdoc" && \
  /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bootstrap -v 4.0.0.alpha6 --no-ri --no-rdoc"

RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/xxx.com

USER node

WORKDIR /home/node/xxx.com

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "./entry.sh"]
```

entry.sh

```
service nginx start
npm install
npm run watch &
compass watch
```

On my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) start works. Running the container (with `-p 8000:80`) everything is fine, but on my Workstation (Ubuntu 14.10) nginx does not start within the container. If I run `docker exec -it -u root <cid> /bin/bash` and then `service nginx start` everything is running.

How can do that without using the extra command? Why is that working on my Laptop and not on my Workstation?

BTW:

Workstation `$ docker version`

```
Client:
  Version:      17.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.27
  Go version:   go1.7.5
  Git commit:   c6d412e
  Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:10:36 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:10:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Laptop:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:35:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:35:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should copy your nginx.sh file into the container and start the container with the shell script as entrypoint?

1. add startskript into container
2. move and set to executable
3. set entrypoint to start skript

   FROM ubuntu:16.10

   ```
   //add start script to temp
   ADD run-nginx.sh  /tmp/

   RUN useradd -m --password=node node && \
   apt-get update && \
   apt-get upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install -y curl && \
   apt-get install -y openssl 

   && \
     apt-get install -y nginx && \
     apt-get -qy autoremove

   COPY . /home/node/xxx.com

   RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && \
     cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled && \
     ln -s /home/node/xxx.com/xxx.nginx.conf default

   WORKDIR /home/node

   RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash - && \
     apt-get install -y nodejs 

   RUN curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable && \
     /bin/bash -l -c "rvm requirements" && \
     /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.0" && \
     /bin/bash -l -c "gem update --system" && \
     /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc" && \
     /bin/bash -l -c "gem install compass  --no-ri --no-rdoc" && \
     /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bootstrap -v 4.0.0.alpha6 --no-ri --no-rdoc"

   //copy to home and set to executable
   RUN mv /tmp/run-nginx.sh / && chmod +x /run-nginx.sh

   RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/xxx.com

   USER node

   WORKDIR /home/node/xxx.com

   ENTRYPOINT ["/run-nginx.sh"]
   ```

Comment: `COPY . /home/node/xxx.com` includes the start script, so it is already there

Comment: okay i didnt know your dir structure. have you tried to set the full entrypoint path for the scirpt? ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "/home/node/xxx.com/entry.sh"]

Comment: Well. The script is running and does what it should. That is not the issue. My Problem is, that nginx does not start on my workstation, but on my laptop. So I guess that is either a permission issue, or that is caused by those different docker versions.